# Probability - Mathematical Expectation

Tags: probability

This is a homework question but I’m not allowed to tag it.

The question is “find the expected number of aces in a poker hand of 5 cards”

Considering this is the chapter on expectancy, I attempted to find e(x) using 1/13 as the probability for getting an ace but im used to doing so using a probability function. The answer in the back of the book is 85/221 but I can’t wrap my head around how to do this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Let $X$ be the number of aces in a 5 card hand. Then $X\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. What's the probability of each event occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the cards the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$ and for $i=1,\dots,5$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if card $i$ is an ace and value $0$ otherwise.

Then the number of aces is:$$X_1+\cdots+X_5$$

Applying linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb E[X_1+\cdots+X_5]=\mathbb EX_1+\cdots+\mathbb EX_5=5\mathbb EX_1=5\mathsf P(X_1=1)=\frac5{13}$$

Comment: This is the best way to think about the problem, and the only answer here that gives an answer; that's important in this case, because the answer that OP states is in the book is incorrect.

Comment: @MarcusM Thank you. However $\frac{85}{221}=\frac5{13}$ so the answers match. No idea how factor $17$ got involved.

Comment: Oh true, that's quite odd.

Comment: I noticed the book changes the format of the answer a lot but this is the text our professor prefers to use. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: As a (minor) variant, let $Y_i$ be the indicator for each ace.  The $i^{th}$ ace is in the hand with probability $\frac 5{52}$ so the answer is $\frac {20}{52}=\frac 5{13}$.  I, too, have no idea how they got the extra factor of $17$.

Comment: @lulu Indeed. In my variant a card in hand wonders: "what is my chance to be an ace?" In yours an ace wonders: "what is my chance to be in the hand?"

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

1) What is the total number of hands?

2) What is the number of hands containing

- one ace?
- two aces?
- ...

Answer (score 1):

HINT

You can get 0,1,2,3, or 4 aces.  Find the probability and multiply by the number of aces for each of those cases

For example, let's do 2 aces.  This means you get 2 aces and 3 non-aces. The probability of that is:

$$\frac{{4 \choose 2} \cdot {48 \choose 3}}{52 \choose 5}$$

And multiply by this by $2$.

Same for 1,3, and 4 aces (no need to do 0 aces), and add them all up

Comment: I assume you mean $\binom{48}{3}$ rather than $\binom{39}{3}$?

Comment: @MarcusM Good catch.

Comment: @MarcusM Thanks! :)